# Cut all till the end

Tags: bash, terminal, grep, cut

I have an out put in the below pattern

```
["snaptuda-shv-22-lla1.example.com","snaptuza-shv-22-lla1.example.com","snaptuservice-proxy-shv-22-lla1.example.com"]
```

I used below command to strip the domains within the double quotes

```sh
cut -d"\"" -f2 file.txt
```

I got only the first domain , which was

> snaptuda-shv-22-lla1.example.com

What I need is all domains till the end of the file , how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You input is [json](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). For parsing json there is [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
jq -r '.[]' filename
```

Or if the input comes from stdout, like this:

```
echo '["snaptuda-shv-22-lla1.example.com",...]' | jq -r '.[]'
snaptuda-shv-22-lla1.example.com
snaptuza-shv-22-lla1.example.com
snaptuservice-proxy-shv-22-lla1.example.com
```